# Unique Key for Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, key, settings

I made a Windows Form GUI which will contain specific products I sell. Obviously in order to use these products, they have to buy a subscription from me. The one easy way to prevent people from doing so would be to use Keygen API. For me, that is a last resort because I don't want a user to have to input their key at all. I have used executables in the past that somehow have their own unique key which the user would just copy and simply give to the person they buy the product from. I would like to do that. For each person that downloads the executable, there is a different key that already comes with the executable. **How can I make it that each download has a different key and that after the download that key won't change?** If my question doesn't make much sense please let me know and I will try to explain again.

Answer (score 0):

After some thinking I actually had an idea. I am sure there are much better ways, but I am using the settings tab in the form properties and creating an int that if not is set to 0 it will set another string called uniqueKey in the settings to a unique key. It also will change the value of that int I talked about earlier to something that isn't 0. Therefore if the app is open the first time it will set that the key to that machine. Unfortunately I am not sure as to how this will work with my updates.

Comment: When you change settings values in the User scope, these values are saved in a simple text file in the current User `AppData` folder or all Users `AppData`. When you deploy a new version of your app, you can upgrade the User settings and reflect these settings in the new version. See the [ApplicationSettingsBase.Upgrade](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.upgrade) method.